# VBA, For Loop , subscript out of range on second loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error at `If headers(iheaders, 1) = SR(1, iSR) Then`   First loop works fine. Then Second loop I get `subscript out of range`. But I notice it always loops back to `For iSR = 1 To UBound(SR, 2)` instead of `For iheaders = 1 To UBound(headers, 2)`.

**what the code does:**

Headers on sheet A are supposed to match with those on Sheet B. They are both Horizontal headers.
 where there is a match , assign the 5th row of SR to my variable `R`.

**Code**:

```
Const FirstMatch As Boolean = True
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim SR As Variant
Dim iSR As Integer
Dim R As Variant
Dim headers As Variant
Dim iheaders As Integer

    SR = Worksheets("Sheet A").Range("D3:J7").Value  
    headers = Worksheets("Sheet B").Range("B1:H1").Value

    With Worksheets("Sheet B")

        ReDim R(1 To UBound(SR), 1 To 1)

    For iheaders = 1 To UBound(headers, 2)

        For iSR = 1 To UBound(SR, 2)

            If headers(iheaders, 1) = SR(1, iSR) Then

            R(iSR, 1) = SR(5, iSR)

                If FirstMatch Then

                     Exit For

                 End If

            End If

        Next

    Next


    'Populate R to where I want on Total Page

    End With
```

Comment: should be `If headers(1, iheaders) = SR(1, iSR) Then` the problem is that the `headers` array only has a single row, but you put the variable in the row field instead of the column field.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it, although now I get a subscript error later on at `R(iSR, 1) = SR(5, iSR)`

Comment: you need to change how you redim `R`: `ReDim R(1 To UBound(SR, 2), 1 To 1)`

Comment: Caught it :P, thanks. One last question.. I am assigning all these values to R.. then when I paste R (`.Range("B" & lastrow + 1 & ":" & "H" & lastrow + 1).Value = R`) it only uses the first match value and pastes that across in this range.

Comment: `.Range("B" & lastrow + 1 & ":" & "H" & lastrow + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(R)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184349/discussion-between-excelguy-and-tigeravatar).